# how to write aws dynamodb scan filter

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have one dynamodb table and one record is like belwo:

```
{
    "Items": [
        {
            "toObjectId": {
                "S": "5678"
            },         
            "keyValue": {
                "S": "7890"
            },
            "aTypeId": {
                "S": "test"
            },
            "aws:rep:deleting": {
                "BOOL": false
            },
            "currentAt": {
                "N": "1582476260000"
            },
            "keyTypeId": {
                "S": "test2"
            },
            "aId": {
                "S": "1234"
            },
            "aTypeId_keyTypeId_keyValue_currentAt": {
                "S": "test_test2_7890_1582476260000"
            },
            "fromObjectId": {
                "S": "12345"
            },

        }
    ],
    "Count": 2562,
    "ScannedCount": 2562,
    "ConsumedCapacity": null

}
```

How can I write one aws dynamodb scan/query filter with aws cli to just get aTypeId and aId when aTypeId is "test"?
And

```
Primary partition key is aId (String)
Primary sort key is aTypeId_keyTypeId_keyValue_currentAt (String)
```

I have tried below but no lucky with it

```
aws dynamodb query \
    --table-name test \
    --key-condition-expression "aTypeId = :aTypeId" \
    --expression-attribute-values '{
        ":aTypeId": { "S": "test" }     
    }'
```

Comment: What is the Primary Key for the table? And does the table has Sort Key too?

Comment: Thanks a lot @PopoiMenenet, I have updated the question with the sort key and primary key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You field is not in a key or GSI (Global secondary index), then I think you have to use `scan` method to get object by `aTypeId`,

The query will like:

```
aws dynamodb scan \
     --table-name test \
     --filter-expression "aTypeId = :typeValue" \
     --projection-expression "aTypeId, aId" \
     --expression-attribute-values '{":typeValue":{"S":"test"}}'
```

If you get back result with `LastEvaluatedKey` value, this mean you need take one or more query to get all data:

```
aws dynamodb scan \
     --table-name test \
     --filter-expression "aTypeId = :typeValue" \
     --projection-expression "aTypeId, aId" \
     --starting-token VALUE_NEXT_TOKEN_OF_LAST_QUERY \
     --expression-attribute-values '{":typeValue":{"S":"test"}}'
```

But, I recommended that create a GSI with `aTypeId` is hash key will be better.

Answer (score 2):

Since `aId` is a Primary Key and you are trying to search for it, you can only scan through the table (which is might be very expensive operation). Try below command to scan the item

```
aws dynamodb scan \
 --table-name test \
 --projection-expression "aTypeId, aId" \
 --filter-expression "aTypeId = :aTypeId" \
 --expression-attribute-values '{":aTypeId":{"S":"test"}}'
```

As a precaution, a single `Scan` request will only return up to 1MB size of data. If there is anymore data to scan, the response from the request will append `LastEvaluatedKey` and that tells you to run `Scan` request again to find the item, but this time with `--starting-token` and the value is exactly `LastEvaluatedKey`

If this type of operation is a routine in your case, it will be better to use `Global Secondary Index` and use `aTypeId` as Primary Key